# Publishing an Excel Workbook in Sharepoint Site

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2007, adfs

I have an excel workbook and I need to publish it in a SharePoint site using Excel VBA. So I created a method in a module using the below code:

```
Private sc_Lists As SoapClient30

Public c_WSDL_URL As String

Private Const c_SERVICE As String = "Lists"

Private Const c_PORT As String = "ListsSoap"

Private Const c_SERVICE_NAMESPACE As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"


Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim str_WSML As String
    str_WSML = ""
    Set sc_Lists = New SoapClient30
    c_WSDL_URL = glb_URL

    sc_Lists.MSSoapInit2 c_WSDL_URL, str_WSML, c_SERVICE, c_PORT, c_SERVICE_NAMESPACE

    sc_Lists.ConnectorProperty("WinHTTPAuthScheme") = &H1
    sc_Lists.ConnectorProperty("UseSSL") = True
    sc_Lists.ConnectorProperty("AuthUser") = "username"
    sc_Lists.ConnectorProperty("AuthPassword") = "pass"

End Sub
```

The problem is when I open the excel document and try to publish it then it asks for the credentials of my SharePoint site even though I have provided them in the code as can be seen above. What I need is to prevent asking credentials when publishing.

Answer (score 2):

I've had auth issues when attempting to push to SP using VBA; it is simply to fragile and finicky. One solution I've used at my work is instead to map the SP site as a network drive and simply save the file directly [(like in this UC tutorial)](https://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=32514), thus avoiding this problem.