# use Excel vba to copy a folder to sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy a folder to SharePoint using VBA and if so is there sample code on how this is done

Many thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

You can [publish an Excel file to Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639071/publishing-an-excel-workbook-in-sharepoint-site) (a.k.a. *Chèvre-poing*), but it looks rather difficult since the authentication mechanism is ill tampered (like goats).

So what you should do is **map a local Share with Sharepoint** (`\\my_chevre_poing\goaty\`, then have a little VBA do it from your favorite macro place:

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\local\trucs\"              '<< your own source there
    ToPath = "\\my_chevre_poing\goaty_trucs\" '<< your share there

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

You also may find [huge resource there](http://kelsoe.com/vba-copy-move-and-delete-files-and-folders/).